# How to use Apache spark as Query Engine?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

i am using Apache Spark For Big data Processing. The data is loaded to Data frames from a Flat file source or JDBC source. The Job is to search specific records from the data frame using spark sql.

So i have to Run the job again and again for new search terms. every time i have to submit the Jar files using spark submit to get the results. **As the size of data is 40.5 GB it becomes tedious to reload the same data every time to data frame to get the results for different queries**.

so What i need is,

> - a way if i can load the data in data frame once and query it multiple time with out submitting the jar multiple times ?
> - if we could use spark as a search engine/ query engine?
> - if we can load the data into data frame once and query the data frame remotely using RestAP
>
> **> The current configuration of My Spark Deployment is**
>
> - 5 node cluster.
> - runs on yarn rm.

i have tried to use spark-job server but it also runs the job every time.

Comment: _if we can query to an existing data frame using spark sql using Rest Api ?_ - yup. _if we could use spark as a search engine/ query engine?_ - opinion based but with 40GB of data just use decent RDBMS. You'll get much better ROI. _a way if i can load the data frame once_ - more than one. From builitin thrift server to different rest options and data grids.

Comment: @zero323 it would be good. if can you explain more precisely ?

Comment: @KamalPradhan It should be possible to keep an RDD cached between jobs using spark-jobserver. I think you have to name your RDD for it to work. See [here](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver#named-objects) fore details

Comment: @GrahamS the problem is we have to query data frame using spark-sql. so if we can load the data into data frame once and query the data frame remotely using RestAPI my problem will be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in [HiveThriftServer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer) and Spark integration.

Basically you start a Hive Thrift Server and inject your HiveContext build from SparkContext:

```
...
val sql = new HiveContext(sc)
sql.setConf("hive.server2.thrift.port", "10001")
...
dataFrame.registerTempTable("myTable")
HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext(sql)
...
```

There are several client libraries and tools to query the server:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients

Including CLI tool - ***beeline***

Reference:
https://medium.com/@anicolaspp/apache-spark-as-a-distributed-sql-engine-4373e254e0f9#.3ntbhdxvr

Comment: thanks that'll help a lot. Can we query the server using rest api or some web service. will it also be able to scale in yarn cluster mode.

Comment: You have dedicated java (JDBC), python and ruby libraries that can query this service - It's mentioned in the response - the "Clients" link

Comment: Please also check the official documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#distributed-sql-engine

Answer (score 0):

You can also use spark+kafka streaming integration. Just that you will have to send your queries over kafka for the streaming APIs to pick up. Thats one design pattern picking up quickly in market cos if its simplicity.

1. Create Datasets over your lookup data.
2. Start a Spark streaming query over Kafka.
3. Get the sql from your Kafka topic
4. Execute the query over the already created Datasets

This should take care of your usecase.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For the spark search engine, if you require full text search capabilities and/or document level scoring - and you do not have an elasticsearch infrastructure - you can give a try to [Spark Search](https://github.com/phymbert/spark-search) - it brings [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) support to [spark](https://spark.apache.org/).

```scala
df.rdd.searchRDD().save("/tmp/hdfs-pathname")
val restoredSearchRDD: SearchRDD[Person] = SearchRDD.load[Person](sc, "/tmp/hdfs-pathname")
restoredSearchRDD.searchList("(fistName:Mikey~0.8) OR (lastName:Wiliam~0.4) OR (lastName:jonh~0.2)",
                            topKByPartition = 10)
                 .map(doc => s"${doc.source.firstName}=${doc.score}"
                 .foreach(println)
```